# Can I use Visual Studio project to keep database scripts ?

Tags: database, visual-studio

Is it possible to keep the all of my database scripts in VS?  
Is there an easy way or would I have to create the scripts from the database and manually add that file into my VS project?

Comment: You can create a folder inside of Visual Studio and save your scripts to that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in fact recent versions of Visual Studio have a type of project just for this - [Database Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xee70aty(v=vs.100).aspx)

There's also [SQL Server Database Tools (SSDT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx), which is kind of the same idea, but its own package if you don't have a version of VS that supports it on its own. I believe SSDT has been superseded by Database Projects in VS.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this, hopefully it will work easily with Oracle DB.

Comment: You should specify the database in your question. SSDT and VS Database Projects greatly prefer to work with SQL Server. You can put plain SQL scripts (files) in your projects just like any other item/file, but they may not work as well if they're not part of a DB project.

Comment: I have the good old scripts now, but that is a manual process to keep them synced.

Comment: You can put them in a folder in your project to keep them versioned. Then use whatever process you already have to deploy changes to your database objects via those scripts.

Comment: To setup Oracle files you must 1) Create a Data Connection, 2) Create a Oracle Database Project.  Then from the Data Connection you can add the files to your project.